# Aura Iteration not detecting change event

Tags: lightning, aura, aura-handler

I have a test setup, but i am unable to get it working. I have lightning page which shows Names of few accounts as an inputText using aura:iteration. I need to detect any change made by user on these inputText boxes. But change event doesnt seem to fire. Can anyone tell me what am i doing wrong here?

Aura App code

```
<aura:application controller="AutoSaveAppController" >
    <aura:attribute name="accts" type="Account[]"/>


    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.accts}" action="{!c.acctsChanged}"/>

    <aura:iteration items="{!v.accts}" var="currAcct" indexVar="index">
        <ui:inputText label="Acct  " value="{!currAcct.Name}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:application>
```

Aura client side controller -

```
({
    doInit : function(cmp, evt, helper) {
        var getAccts = cmp.get("c.loadAccounts");
        getAccts.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS"){
                var allAccts = response.getReturnValue();
                cmp.set("v.accts", allAccts);
            }else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(getAccts);
    },

    acctsChanged :function(cmp, evt, helper){
      console.log("Change Detected");  
    }
})
```

Aura server side controller -

```
public class AutoSaveAppController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static Account[] loadAccounts(){
        Account[] randomAccts = [Select Name From Account limit 10];
        return randomAccts;
    }
}
```

On the page load, it should show names of few accounts in a text box. And when i change something in those boxes (and move mouse out of that box and click somewhere else), developer console should show "Change detected". But nothing is happening.

Answer (score 3):

I think your `acctsChanged` method will only be called when the `accts` list attribute is changed not when the `Name` field of one of the items in the list is changed.

So for this case use:

```
<ui:inputText label="Acct  " value="{!currAcct.Name}" keyup="{!c.acctsChanged}"/>
```

Comment: Yeah i got that working too. But this is just a sample code. Actual implementation has lot of fields. Is there a way where if any field on any account changes, that event is fired (without putting "change" on every field)

Comment: @user11287638 I assume that checking every node of what could be a large object tree is to expensive for the platform hence its necessary to declare the ones you are interested in. I don't know if there is a more elegant approach than many change handlers.